# specify array of string in pyspark schema

Tags: pyspark, schema

how can I specify an array of string in the pyspark sql schema.
I dont want to use StructFields.

in the following example, cities are in array list.

```
schema = "country string, cities array(string)"
df=spark.read.csv(file_path,schema=schema)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<>` instead of parentheses

```
schema = "country string, cities array<string>"
```